# How to download a blob as mp4 in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have the following code snippet to download a blob

```
 let blob = new window.Blob(dataOrg);
      let anchor = document.createElement('a');
      anchor.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
      anchor.download = "downloadssss";
      anchor.textContent = 'video/mp4';
      anchor.style.display = 'none';
      document.body.appendChild(anchor);

      if (anchor.click) {
        anchor.click();

      } else {

        var evt = document.createEvent('MouseEvents');
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        evt.initMouseEvent('click', true, true, window, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, false, false, false, false, 0, null);
        anchor.dispatchEvent(evt);
      }
```

The blob that I am constructing from `dataOrg` is a DataArray i obtain from peerJS. I want the downloaded file to be a .mp4 file but using this code the downloaded file is of file format.It opens as video in Desktop but cannot be opened in mobile device. Is there any way to download it as a mp4 file?

Comment: To `anchor.download` you have to assign `filename.mp4`. Filename can be anything, but '.mp4' is a string appended to the filename.

Comment: i did that too. If i do so the file doesnot even open in Desktop

Comment: This file isn't playable. That might be because the file type is unsupported, the file extension is incorrect, or the file is corrupt.

Comment: But you are sure your data _is_ actually that of an mp4 file? What file suffix was it saved under before, when it was still working on desktop? Maybe it is a different file format, so without a proper ending your OS kinda “guessed” what format it is, but now with `.mp4` you are preventing it from guessing, and it expects mp4 data and won’t play anything else? Dunno, this lacks too much detail so far to be able to say anything else at this point.

Comment: Yeah i am sending a mp4 file from FireFox in my desktop to my chrome browser using peerJS. i first convert it into DaraArray and send to chrome

Comment: Are you sure that all the chunks have been sent from firefox? As suggested by SKT u definitely need to add the .mp4 extension but if you try to construct a mp4 file without all the chunks ofcourse you will get an error

Comment: yeah that was the problem. I made an error in my logic, so i didnot add the last chunk to the blob.